# React Router: some internal Link re-download the App

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have the following config for my routes:

```
import React from 'react'
import {Route, IndexRedirect} from 'react-router'

import MainView from '../pages/pro/main'
import MyJobsListView from '../pages/pro/my-jobs'
import MyJobsTabAccepted from '../pages/pro/my-jobs/tabs/Accepted'
import MyJobsTabLeads from '../pages/pro/my-jobs/tabs/Leads'

import JobView from '../pages/pro/job'
import JobViewTabQuote from '../pages/pro/job/tabs/Quote'

const jobRoutes = (
  <Route name='pro-job' path=':jobUuid' component={JobView}>
    <Route name='pro-job-messages' path='messages' />
    <Route name='pro-job-quote' path='quote' component={JobViewTabQuote} />
    <IndexRedirect to='messages' />
  </Route>
)

const jobsRoutes = (
  <Route component={MyJobsListView}>
    <Route
      name='pro-jobs-accepted'
      path='accepted'
      component={MyJobsTabAccepted}
      />
    <Route
      name='pro-jobs-leads'
      path='leads'
      component={MyJobsTabLeads}
      />
  </Route>
)

export default (
  <Route component={MainView}>
    <Route name='pro-jobs' path='my-jobs'>
      {jobsRoutes}
      {jobRoutes}
      <IndexRedirect to='accepted' />
    </Route>
    <IndexRedirect to='my-jobs' />
  </Route>
)
```

In `MyJobsTabAccepted` I have Links to `pro-job` route, defined as:

```
<Link
  className={className}
  to={{
    name: 'pro-job',
    params: {...routerUtils.getParams().toJS(), jobUuid: job.uuid},
  }}
  >
  {job.uuid}
</Link>
```

When I click on this Link the page is downloaded again and the app is restarted. I can't find any way to fix this.

I use `use-named-routes` which works well in the rest of the application.

The `Link` component is created in a component which is, for more reasons, also wrapped with `withRouter`.

For some reason these Links are created in a "builder-hidden" div and moved where I need with the follow function:

```
  _moveItems () {
    _.forEach(this.builder.children, c => {
      this.container.appendChild(c.cloneNode(true))
    })
  }
```

It looks like react does not know anything about them, and so they are handled as normal links.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `/` before your path. For example `/mypath`.

```
<Link to="/mypath">My path</Link>
```

Comment: Oh I see the problem!

I move those Links with this function:

  _moveItems () {
    _.forEach(this.builder.children, c => {
      this.container.appendChild(c.cloneNode(true))
    })
  }

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the moveItems.

cloneNode does not clone the eventHandlers of the node elements, so I lose completely the functionalities of my components.